# parametricplot/revolutionplot3d color by a function

Tags: plotting, color

I want to draw a ParametricPlot and/or a RevolutionPlot3D of functions `{X[s],Z[s]}` extracted from NDSolve, of which color is determined by a function `H[s]`(curvature). Say, red at maximum `H` and blue at minimum `H`.

This is what I've tried so far referring some other questions and answers

```
Clear[P, Σ0, C0];
eqold[Σ_] = {Z'[s] == -Sin[ψ[s]], ψ''[
     s] == -ψ'[s]/X[s] Cos[ψ[s]] + 
     Cos[ψ[s]] Sin[ψ[s]]/X[s]^2 + γ[s]/
       X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + P X[s]/2 Cos[ψ[s]], γ'[
     s] == (ψ'[s] - C0)^2/2 - Sin[ψ[s]]^2/(2 X[s]^2) + 
     P X[s] Sin[ψ[s]] + Σ, X'[s] == Cos[ψ[s]]};
help[eq_] := (Subtract @@ eq // Together // Numerator) == 0
P = 1;
Σ0 = -0.7393598769972676`;
C0 = -0;
a = -0.25883351091296464`;
spsoln[a_] = 
  NDSolve[{eqold[Σ0][[{1, 4}]], 
    help /@ eqold[Σ0][[{2, 3}]], A'[s] == 2 π X[s], 
    A[0] == 0, V'[s] == π X[s]^2 Sin[ψ[s]], 
    V[0] == 0, ψ[0] == 0, ψ'[0] == a, 
    X[0] == 0, γ[0] == 0, Z[0] == 0}, {X, ψ, Z, γ, 
    A, V}, {s, 0, 20}, SolveDelayed -> True];
s1 = 4.769812938286635`;
H[s_] = 1/
    2 (Evaluate[ψ'[s] /. spsoln[a]] + 
     Sin[Evaluate[ψ[s] /. spsoln[a]]]/(Evaluate[
        X[s] /. spsoln[a]]));
Hmin = FindMinimum[H[s], {s, 0}][[1]]; // Quiet
Hmax = FindMaximum[H[s], {s, 4}][[1]]; // Quiet
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln[a]], {s, 0, s1}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{X, ψ, u}, 
   ColorData["Pastel"][Rescale[H[u], {Hmax, Hmin}, {0, 1}]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln[a]], {s, 0, s1}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{X, ψ, s}, 
   ColorData["Pastel"][Rescale[H[u], {Hmax, Hmin}, {0, 1}]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

This runs normally without any error but doesn't affect the color.

Can anyone figure out what am I missing or suggest me ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: The problem is that `H` is vector-valued, not scalar-valued. Try `Function[{X, \[Psi], u}, 
 ColorData["Pastel"][Rescale[H[u][[1]], {Hmax, Hmin}, {0, 1}]]]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for the comment! However, I am still getting the same outputs. Should I touch somewhere else as well?

Comment: Actually,, I realized that this code works with my desktop while not working with my laptop...my laptop pops up Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. They both are 12.1 version. Very weird... Thank you very much anyway

Comment: Hm. Typically when weird things happen, they are caused by some "hanging" definitions in the _Mathematica_ kernel. Restarting the session (e.g., with `Exit[]`) migth help.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Still the same. The only difference I found is that Mathematica on my desktop is 12.1"student", and one on my laptop is normal 12.1. Maybe I should just work with my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, "Rescale" needs not {Hmax, Hmin}, but {Hmin,Hmax}. Then we need an additional indexing, because H is vector valued. Third, the ColorFunction for RevolutionPlot3D is: "Function[{x, y, z, t, [Theta], r},...". With this corrections:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln[a]], {s, 0, s1}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{X, \[Psi], u}, 
   ColorData["Pastel"][Rescale[H[u], {Hmin, Hmax}, {0, 1}][[1]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[{X[s], Z[s]} /. spsoln[a]], {s, 0, s1}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, t, \[Theta], r}, 
   ColorData["Pastel"][Rescale[H[t], {Hmin, Hmax}, {0, 1}][[1]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problems! Is it correct that this output came out directly by this code, without touching anything else? I copied and pasted this but it gives me ones without color change...

Comment: Actually,, I realized that this code works with my desktop while not working with my laptop...my laptop pops up Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. They both are 12.1 version. Very weird... Thank you very much anyway